# Decoding a weird json file with Dart

Tags: json, flutter, dart, nfc

This needs to be decode into readable JSON with Dart the problem is. I don't what it is and I don't know how to do it.

```
{
mifare: {
identifier: [4, 119, 66, 185, 196, 77, 112], 
mifareFamily: 2, 
historicalBytes: []
}, 
ndef: {
isWritable: true, 
maxSize: 492, 
cachedMessage: 
{records: 
[{identifier: [], 
typeNameFormat: 1, 
type: [84], 
payload: [2, 101, 110, 123, 39, 99, 109, 100, 39, 58, 39, 110, 101, 119, 95, 102, 114, 105, 101, 110, 100, 39, 44, 39, 117, 115, 101, 114, 39, 58, 39, 116, 101, 115, 116, 39, 125]}]}}}
```

Someone any idea how to do that?
PS: the 'payload' should be text like this:

```
{'cmd':'new_friend','user':'test'}
```

Comment: Why don't you ask the party that produces that file? I mean *they* should know, right?

Comment: This isn't a "weird" JSON file, because this isn't valid JSON. You are going to spend more time trying to dynamically convert this file into readable JSON than you would just parsing it as-is. That said, this is a reasonably complex data format so creating a parser yourself wouldn't be a trivial task and there probably isn't an existing parser for it. You should ask whoever provided you with this data for suggestions on how to use it.

Comment: Although now that I look at it, you could convert this data into readable JSON with a simple Regex search and replace to wrap all alphanumeric strings (excluding "true" and "false") with quotation marks. That's based on this one sample though, and there's no guarantee that it will work for every file you ever receive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to convert this in to your text string, then you need to understand the NDEF data format as this looks like a dump of raw data from reading an NFC card with an Ndef record on it.

Not many libraries have a decoding method only encoding methods.

So the Key points are:-

`typeNameFormat: 1` is the code for "Well known Ndef format"

`type: [84]` is the code for Ndef Text Record

This leads you to specification for the Ndef text Record
https://github.com/haldean/ndef/blob/master/docs/NFCForum-TS-RTD_Text_1.0.pdf

Then

`payload: [2, 101, 110, 123, 39, 99, 109, 100, 39, 58, 39, 110, 101, 119, 95, 102, 114, 105, 101, 110, 100, 39, 44, 39, 117, 115, 101, 114, 39, 58, 39, 116, 101, 115, 116, 39, 125]`

the

`2` is 2 bytes for language identifier length

`101` is the decimal code for US ASCII char of `e`

`110` is the decimal code for US ASCII char of `n`

So the text is in English

`123` is the decimal code for US ASCII char of `{`

etc.

Should have said this is not JSON but a dump of a Javascript Object in Javascript

Comment: Thanks! that really helps me out